# Instantiating multiple objects using for loop

Tags: python

Hello I want to instantiate 5 objects of class Philosopher in a single line but I'm getting an IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level. Here is my source code. How to resolve this ?

```
forks=[threading.Lock() for i in range(5)]
philosopherNames={'Shubham','Nikhil','Soham','Khirade','Aditya'}
philosopher= [Philosopher(i, philosopherNames[i], forks[i%5], forks[(i+1)%5]) \ for i in range(5)]
random.seed(507129)
Philospher.running=True 
for p in philosopher:
    p.start()
time.sleep(100)
Philosopher.running=False
print "Now we are ending"
```

Answer (score 0):

Indent errors are exactly that; your file is not indented properly. It has nothing to do with your code, you just have to check carefully to make sure the exact same number of spaces or tabs are used in your script file.

Answer (score -1):

### How to solve

---

Here is your error:

```
philosopher= [Philosopher(i, philosopherNames[i], 
forks[i%5], forks[(i+1)%5]) \ for i in range(5)]
                            ^
```

Just remove that backslash and everything's gonna be all right.

### Why is this happening?

---

`philosopher` list is created with a *list comprehension*, the functional programming bit of Python.

You normally indent loops with tabs / spaces (don't mix the two, though) like this:

```
data = []
for x in range(2, 8):
    data.append(x**2) # indented this
```

With list comprehensions you *don't need any indentation*:

```
data = [x**2 for x in range(2, 8)]
```

As far as I understand, you tried to indent the `for` in your list comprehension with a backslash, which obviously was wrong.

Comment: This is an unrelated problem that would produce a different error message (`SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`).